# Importing a jar file into robocode doesnt work

Tags: java, robocode

I am using robocode 1.9.2.6

I created a simple maven project for my robot. When I import the generated the jar into Robocode UI, Robot-> Import Robot. It says robot imported successfully and the jar file is copied into the robots folder.

After that when I create a new Battle my robot doesnt appear. Tried refreshing and clean cache.

When I set path of my class folder in the preferences->development it works.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: "When I set path of my class folder in the preferences->development it works." Then what's the problem...?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Robocode then only detects the development version of the robot (unpackaged) which is not what he seems to want.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the question, I guess you haven't included the file `MyRobotName.properties` in the resulting `.jar`. Did you build the `.jar` using Maven?

Try packaging the robot with Robocode itself (using the built-in packager) as follows:

- Add your development path as you have written above.
- In the menu bar, go to **Robot - Package robot or team** and add your (development version of the) robot.

The resulting `.jar` file should be found in Robocode.

Alternatively, you can surely configure your build process in a way such that it creates the `.properties` file for you. Just have a look at the one created by the Robocode packager and reconstruct it. That's what I do in my Gradle build process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try it out and get back :)